# Is it really that unsafe to store passwords in a text file on my computer?

Tags: encryption, passwords

These days, we have pretty secure systems.
I have a mac with T2 security chip and the whole disk is encrypted via FileVault.
iPhones are known to be pretty secure, with even FBI having a hard time breaking in.
Windows machines can be encrypted with BitLocker or VeraCrypt.
With these kinds of systems, is it really that unsafe to store passwords in a text file? for an average individual user?
Of course if I'm operating a server or anything like that, I would definitely need better security. But I was wondering how much security does and average individual user really need?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is unsecure. Here are some reasons.

It can be that you installed (intentionally or not) some malware or virus, that scans your files and sends data to some external server.

It can be that your create backups to some external drive and they are not encrypted. If you lost your back up drive, somebody can get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is insecure;

- Full disk encryption protects your data **at rest**. Whilst the computer is running and the disk is in use, processes access storage as if there was no encryption in place. You need further security measures to protect you while the computer is operating: auto locking of smartphone/laptop, strong local password, segregation of privileges, etc;
- Consequently, you are susceptible (as mentioned) to malware that could have infected your machine or that may do in the future. You can have remote control software due to corporate policies, etc;
- Backups could end up unencrypted (as mentioned) thus susceptible to theft and tampering;

A much better approach is to use a password manager. It's still a file stored on your file system but there's multiple advantages to this:

- It is natively encrypted on the file system and good password managers are implemented with great care to not leave behind fragments of the encryption key or stored passwords in memory;
- You can (and should) have longer stronger and unique passwords for all your local and remote services and not reuse them (that you won't have memorised so that's a drawback that needs consideration);

Answer (score 0):

Safe/Unsafe is not a binary condition.

The question really is one of **safe enough**. Passwords to your online news or the Broken Tea Cup Forum are likely of little concern and you are safe enough, assuming of course you don't reuse passwords.

Passwords for your multimillion dollar Swiss Bank Account should probably be protected a little better.

In general, high importance content should not always be open and available to your running machine. How much security/convenience trade off to make is your call.

Again, don't reuse passwords!